# Volumes are not displayed correctly when point lights are activated in the scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

On the right is the volume incl. nodetree, on the left are exactly these objects appended. On the right everything looks great, on the left it's broken and the cubes almost delete each other out.

I have checked: step sizes & render settings are the same (as far as I can see).

[image: volumes appended seem off]

I rechecked and the mistake gets resolved when I deactivate a bunch of objects (meshes and lights).

[image: after deactivation of objects, it works]

I have now identified that the volumes work better (but not bug free), when I deactivate the point lights within the scene. These lights are very small in comparison to the clouds, as they are intended for another part of the scene. How/why could they affect the volumes that massively?

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell but perhaps camera clipping settings, or light paths -> volume bounces.

Comment: Are you sure on the left are Cubes? They looks like a Planes ... also hard to compare for us since light goes from totally opposite direction. Without blend file with an sample really stay in guessing ... sorry.

Comment: @vklidu & Allen, thanks for your help! - I checked your suggestions and yes I am sure these are cubes + I checked the clipping settings. I've edited the post to show my findings. Maybe you've got an idea where to point me with the changes?

Comment: Ok ... See my last sentence in previous comment. It is still hard to understand ... I don't even understand your structure ... Whole cloudy scene consists from one volume split into several cubes in a grid position? Or cubes are overlapping? There is to many Q that is hard to tell without file. It seems to be a huge file, but you can share just a simplified version, that still produce the issue.